# Segfault libc Android

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, libc

I'm using a custom ROM for a Galaxy S5 (KLTE) Fusion 6.0. It's a wonderful ROM but I keep experiencing random soft reboots. I'm trying desperately to track down whatever is causing them. I have a logcat of the issue occurring but I don't know what to make of it. There might be missing pieces to the log as I'm only showing a complete failure.

```
12-23 15:35:18.812 F/libc    (9290): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x1c in tid 9299 (Signal Catcher)

12-23 15:35:18.933 F/libc    (756): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 764 (Signal Catcher)
```

Does anybody know how I could combat this issue? I'm no C programmer.

Comment: sigsegv - is an OS signal meaning "segmentation fault" - which boils down to unsafe memory access.  Assuming no hardware failures - it means either the OS or one of the many app's installed on your OS is accessing memory in an unsafe/incorrect manner.  If you don't know what process/application is causing the issue - then you might want to consider a clean reinstall of your OS.

Comment: This is on Android. I have reinstalled the ROM several times. How would I check if its a hardware failure

Comment: Also based off log wouldn't it mean Signal Catcher is accessing memory it shouldn't be? @Tim